# Loop through all public attributes in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User model with some attributes that are public (Editable by the user) and some that are private (Salt etc).

Assume that the model have N many public attributes (Email and Surname for example) and M private attributes (Salt, confirmation_token for example)

Want i want to do is something like

```
user.attrs.each |name, value| do 
   something(name, value) 
end
```

Could I make use of attr_accessor somehow?

Using rails 4.0.2 and ruby 2.0.0

Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: show us your model too..

Comment: Ruby objects don't really have public attributes, just public methods. For that reason, this is a fairly difficult problem to solve. For Rails though, you may be able to loop through the database columns associated with a ActiveRecord model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have more allowed attributes than disallowed, so I would create an array of protected attribute names and ignore those when looping through the attributes.

```
protected_attributes = %w(password salt confirmation_token)

user.attributes.each do |name, value|
  unless protected_attributes.include?(name)
    something(name, value)
  end
end
```